# Recieve NSMutableAttributedString in mac service bundle

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspasteboard

I am creating a mac .service bundle that receives rich text from applications. TextEdit and notes seem to have no problem writing rich text to the general pasteboard but when the same data is delivered on the service pasteboard there are no attributes on the string. Is this a problem with the service implementation in these programs or is there a way around this? Here is the code I am using to access the pasteboard:

```
- (void)strikeService:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error{

// Test for strings on the pasteboard.
NSMutableAttributedString *pboardString;
NSMutableAttributedString *output;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *classes;

classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSAttributedString class], nil];
NSArray *attributedStrings = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
if (attributedStrings != nil) {
    pboardString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[attributedStrings objectAtIndex:0]];
}


classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString class], nil];
NSArray *strings = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
if (strings != nil && attributedStrings == nil) {
    pboardString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[strings objectAtIndex:0]];
}
output = ...// do something with input

// Write the formatted string onto the pasteboard.
[pboard clearContents];
[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:output]];
```

}

Basically my problem is that pboardString has no attributes unless I fetch from the general pasteboard for both textedit and notes. Why is this and how can I fix it?

UPDATE: It appears from calling [pboard types] that when called from a service, the only UTIs that are returned to the pasteboard are NSStringPboardType and public.utf8-plain-text in Notes and TextEdit but when the general clipboard is called, then these programs post a public.rtf data type. So effectively, a service cannot access the attributes, but can post attributed strings back to the app. Is there a way to find the string attributes of highlighted text?